# How can I calculate the highest difference of values between two immediate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table that follows this structure:

**Table Foo**

```
id          number
---------------------
1             5
2             8
3             3
4             67
5             1
6             10
```

From this table, I want to execute a `SELECT` that shows the number that has grown the most from one row to the immediate next one. Given this example, I would like to see as an output:

```
id          number
---------------------
4             67
```

Because the previous row (with `id = 3`) had a `number` value of `3`, and the next row increased the value up to `67`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does `id` values have no gaps with guarantee? What is MySQL version?

Comment: There might be gaps, I'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it for your sample data is with a self join:

```
select f1.*
from Foo f1 inner join Foo f2
on f2.id = f1.id - 1
order by f1.number - f2.number desc limit 1
```

If there are gaps between the ids then you must find the previous id for each id and then retrieve the number in the previous row:

```
select t.id, t.number
from (
  select f1.id, f1.number, max(f2.id) previd
  from Foo f1 inner join Foo f2
  on f2.id < f1.id
  group by f1.id, f1.number
) t inner join Foo f
on f.id = t.previd
order by t.number - f.number desc limit 1
```

Or:

```
select f.*
from Foo f
order by number - (select number from Foo where id < f.id order by id desc limit 1) desc 
limit 1
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can use LAG() window function:

```
select *
from Foo
order by number - lag(number) over (order by id) desc limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6eda3ab6031de4fe54f807b5829daed2).

Answer (score 1):

> There might be gaps, I'm using MySQL 5.7 – user157629

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.num
FROM foo t1
JOIN foo t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM foo t3
                   WHERE t1.id < t3. id
                     AND t3.id < t2.id )
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.num
ORDER BY t2.num - t1.num DESC, t2.id LIMIT 1;
```

If there is 2 pairs with the same and maximal growth then the row with the least `id` will be returned.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0cfe5e42abd2b94f698470ee9f1ad78c)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this, but i think i over-complicated things

```
select * from (
    select n1.id as 'from' , n2.id as 'to', n2.number- n1.number as growth from 
 (  select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, id, number from numbers
    join (select @rownum :=0) as r1
 ) as n1
 left join (
    select @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum, id, number from numbers
    join (select @rownum2 :=0) as r2
    where id <> (select min(id) from numbers)
 ) as n2
 on n1.rownum = n2.rownum
) as mess

order by growth desc
limit 1
```